Can anyone be plagued by stree shapa?
As I understand, this curse manifests in one's life if a female has been mistreated (in a previous birth).
Is there anything else to add to this? Can people of both genders be inflicted by this curse, or only males?
Google doesn't provide much information on this.

@Narasimham thanks for the correction. Took the spelling from a website.

so pl. delete this comment.
